# Calculating if or not a 3D eyepoint is behind a 2D plane or upwards

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, geometry, vector-graphics

### The setup

Draw XY-coordinate axes on a piece of paper. Write a word on it along X-axis, so that the word's centerpoint is at origo (half on positive side of X/Y, the other half on negative side of X/Y).

Now, if you flip the paper upside down you'll notice that the word is mirrored in relation to both X- and Y-axis. If you look from behind the paper, it's mirrored in relation to Y-axis. If you look at it from behind and upside down, it's mirrored in relation to X-axis.

Ok, I have points in 2D-plane (*vertices*) that are created in similar way at the origo and I need to apply exactly the same rule for them. To make things interesting:

1. The 2D plane is actually 3D, each point (*vertex*) being (x, y, 0). Initially the vertices are positioned to the origo and their normal is **Pn**(0,0,1). => Correctly seen when looked at from point **Pn** towards origo.
2. The vertex-plane has it's own rotation matrix **[Rp]** and position **P**(x,y,z) in the 3D-world. The rotation is applied before positioning.
3. The 3D world is "right handed". The viewer would be looking towards origo from some distance along positive Z-axis but the world is also oriented by rotation matrix **[Rw]**. **[Rw]** * (0,0,1) would point directly to the viewer's eye.

From those I need to calculate when the vertex-plane should be mirrored and by which axis. The mirroring itself can be done before applying **[Rp]** and **P** by:

```
Vertices vertices = Get2DPlanePoints();

int MirrorX = 1; // -1 to mirror, 1 NOT to mirror
int MirrorY = 1; // -1 to mirror, 1 NOT to mirror

Matrix WorldRotation = GetWorldRotationMatrix();    

MirrorX = GetMirrorXFactor(WorldRotation);
MirrorY = GetMirrorYFactor(WorldRotation);

foreach(Vertex v in vertices)
{
  v.X = v.X * MirrorX * MirrorY;
  v.Y = V.Y * MirrorY;
}

// Apply rotation...

// Add position...
```

### The question

So I need GetMirrorXFactor() & ..YFactor() -functions that return -1 if the viewer's eyepoint is at greater "X/Y"-angle than +-90 degrees in relation to the vertex-plane's normal after the rotation and world orientation. **I have already solved this, but I'm looking for more "elegant" mathematics.** I know that rotation matrices somehow contain info about how much is rotated by which axis and I believe that can be utilized here.

### My Solution for MirrorX:

```
// Matrix multiplications. Vectors are vertical matrices here.
Pnr = [Rp] * Pn      // Rotated vertices's normal
Pur = [Rp] * (0,1,0) // Rotated vertices's "up-vector"
Wnr = [Rw] * (0,0,1) // Rotated eye-vector with world's orientation 
                     // = vector pointing directly at the viewer's eye

// Use rotated up-vector as a normal some new plane and project viewer's 
// eye on it. dot = dot product between vectors.
Wnrx = Wnr - (Wnr dot Pur) * Pur // "X-projected" eye. 

// Calculate angle between eye's X-component and plane's rotated normal.
// ||V|| = V's norm.
angle = arccos( (Wnrx dot Pnr) / ( ||Wnrx|| * ||Pnr|| ) )

if (angle > PI / 2)
  MirrorX = -1; // DO mirror
else
  MirrorX = 1;  // DON'T mirror
```

Solution for mirrorY can be done in similar way using viewer's up and vertex-plane's right -vectors.

Better solution?

Comment: A solution without `arccos` is possible, but your terminology is unclear (e.g. it is unclear what `Rw` is or does). How about "mirroring" X if ([Rp](1,0,0)) dot (1,0,0) < 0?

Comment: @Beta [Rw] is the world's orientation. [Rw] * (0,0,1) would point directly to the viewers eye. So I guess you're suggesting something like "MirrorX if ([Rp](1,0,0)) dot [Rw](1,0,0) < 0"? That sounds somewhat promising because I know dot product is negative if angle between the vectors is more than 90 degrees. Care to explain that a bit further?

Comment: I think you'll get a better answer if you describe more qualitatively what you are trying to do. It sounds to me like you are trying to mirror text under a 3D transform such that the text maintains its general shape under transformation, but the text remains readable (upright and left-to-right). Is that correct?

Comment: Would [Rw] (1,0,0) point to the viewer's right?

Comment: @dsharlet That's exactly what I'm trying to do ...and actually I did it already :) But the question is if it's possible to do it in more "elegant" way. I have a feeling that just multiplying both rotation matrices would some how give me a matrix that would contain total rotation around each axis. Maybe from that matrix I could somehow get relative "upwards" angle from rotation around Z-axis etc..?

Comment: @Beta Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (([Rp]*(1,0,0)) dot ([Rw]*(1,0,0))) < 0
  MirrorX = -1; // DO mirror
else
  MirrorX = 1;  // DON'T mirror


if (([Rp]*(0,1,0)) dot ([Rw]*(0,1,0))) < 0
  MirrorY = -1; // DO mirror
else
  MirrorY = 1;  // DON'T mirror
```

Explaining in more detail is difficult without diagrams, but if you have trouble with this solution we can work through some cases.

Comment: I tried this solution on my code. It works correctly if I have some rotation only around one of the axes, but fails otherwise. I'm sorry I'm not able to give more specific description about how it fails. All I know is that the mirroring factors won't be as the should.

Comment: @SimoErkinheimo: If you can't give a more specific description, like an ***example***, then I can't help you.